# Is gcd(a, b+c) equal to gcd(gcd(a, b), gcd(a, c))

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, divisibility, gcd-and-lcm

Is there any relation between gcd(a, b+c) and gcd(gcd(a, b), gcd(a, c)).
I have proved that gcd(gcd(a, b), gcd(a, c)) divides gcd(a, b+c). But, what is exact gcd(a,b+c)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: If $p$ divides $b$ and $c$ then it divides $b+c$. But a complete factorisation of $b+c$ tells you nothing about the primes dividing $b$ or $c$. In general primes may divide $a$ and $b+c$ but not $b$ or $c$.

Comment: not really, the later can be 1, if $\gcd(b,c)=1$,or,  if either one of $b,c$ don't share a factor with $a$. gcd of 2 happens any time they are all even, etc.

Comment: $a=3$, $b=2$, $c=1$.

Answer (score 0):

Using the shorthand notation $(x,y)$ for gcd$(x,y)$ one result connecting $(a,b),(a,c)$ and $(a,b+c)$  is the simple 
$$((a,b)(a,c))=((a,c)(a,b+c))=((a,b+c)(a,b)).$$